# How to get Device Display Name in VC++?

Tags: visual-c++, mouse, device

I can successfully query my system with GetRawInputDeviceList to get a list of raw devices and GetRawInputDeviceInfo to get detailed info on individual devices.

However GetRawInputDeviceInfo returns the "device path" when the name is queried.  What I would like to get is the "display name" as show in the

Device Manager -> Mice and Other Pointing devices -> (mouse device) -> Properties -> Details -> Display Name

How is this possible?

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the "RIDI_DEVICENAME" is a path in the registry. So I can use this to do a Registry look up and grab the last delimted element form the 'DeviceDesc' key.

Thanks - I hope helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

```
UINT WINAPI GetRawInputDeviceInfo(
  __in_opt     HANDLE hDevice,
  __in         UINT uiCommand,
  __inout_opt  LPVOID pData,
  __inout      PUINT pcbSize
);
```

Did you try, `uiCommand = RIDI_DEVICENAME` ?

`GetRawInputDeviceInfo` Reference: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645597(v=VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645597%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Please see my question:  I amble to use GetRawInputDeviceInfo to gather the name (using RIDI_DEVICENAME) - that returns some sort of system name that looks like this: "\\?\ACPI#AUI1500#4&27fd7cf0&1#{378de44c-56ef-11d1-bc8c-00a0c91405dd}".  Looking at the Device manager, this name is actually the "device path".  What I'm looking for is the "device name" which should come back with something like "Alps Pointing-device (2-way)"